# Why this jquery function is looping its-self?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, i display some text in a table and i add a "read-more" button that unwraps the texts.  But when i click this button i want to display at the same time the whole text in the "div#selectedItem".  If "read-more" button is clicked for another text i want to replace that text with the current. The problem here is when i debug my code, i see that when breakpoint reaches the end of function it starts again from the beggining.  why this is happening?

```
$(".table tbody").on("click",
    ".read-more",
    function readMore(e) {        
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        var cellText = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        if (clickedTimes > 0)
            $("div#selectedItem").html("");
        $("div#selectedItem").prepend(cellText).html();
        clickedTimes++;
        setTimeout(readMore, 1000);
});
```

I expect that my function will work for each click independently.

Comment: where is clickedTimes ?

Comment: this function is an inner function. ClickedTimes is declared above.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the end of each call, you have a `setTimeout` which re-calls the function. Remove this and your code will no longer recursively loop:

```
$(".table tbody").on("click", ".read-more", function readMore(e) {        
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var cellText = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
    $(this).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (clickedTimes > 0)
        $("div#selectedItem").html("");
    $("div#selectedItem").prepend(cellText).html();
    clickedTimes++;
});
```

Comment: Mr. Jack i did but there is another issue now.  When the function ends it redirects me to the jquery-3.3.1 file and while im clicking on f10 to continue it brings me back to my function and executes it again.  In first execution i get my cellText displayed in #selectedItem but it recursively loop 14 times. (my counter become 14)  When i stop the debugger and i click on other read-more button it does not nothing!

Comment: I solved it! i should add each(function)! thank you!